# How can I get my entire InputPath as my Payload while also injecting a new field?

Tags: aws-cdk, jsonpath, aws-step-functions

In another question, I asked how I can [include the executionId of a step function workflow as part of the input to my Lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74737365/access-context-object-when-defining-a-step-function-workflow-in-the-cdk), and this was the solution:

```js
new tasks.LambdaInvoke(this, "InvokeLambdaTask", {
  lambdaFunction: myLambda,
  payload: sfn.TaskInput.fromObject({
    executionId: sfn.JsonPath.stringAt("$$.Execution.Id"),
  }),
})
```

This works wonderfully.

However, previously, I was leaving my payload unspecified, so I would get my entire InputPath as the payload. I would like to still have my entire InputPath as my payload, but with the addition of the executionId.

I am trying to avoid redundantly specifying each field,

```js
new tasks.LambdaInvoke(this, "InvokeLambdaTask", {
  lambdaFunction: myLambda,
  payload: sfn.TaskInput.fromObject({
    executionId: sfn.JsonPath.stringAt("$$.Execution.Id"),
    foo: sfn.JsonPath.stringAt("$.foo"),
    bar: sfn.JsonPath.stringAt("$.bar"),
    ...
  }),
})
```

I'm not sure how to express this in CDK/JsonPath in a concise way. I've tried a variety of approaches based on answers to [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63137058/18579129) that don't work and probably don't even make sense, like `".$": sfn.JsonPath.stringAt("$")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to have all the fields of your InputPath at the same level as the injected field, but you can inject the whole thing as a nested JSON object using `objectAt("$")`.

For example:

```js
new tasks.LambdaInvoke(this, "InvokeLambdaTask", {
  lambdaFunction: myLambda,
  payload: sfn.TaskInput.fromObject({
    executionId: sfn.JsonPath.stringAt("$$.Execution.Id"),
    inputPath: sfn.JsonPath.objectAt("$"),
  }),
})
```

Then you just need to refactor your Lambda function to accept the input in this format. For example, my lambda, which is in Kotlin:

```kotlin
data class InputPath(val foo: String, val bar: String)

data class Payload(val executionId: String, val inputPath: InputPath)

...
    override fun handleRequest(event: Payload, context: Context?) = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach to injecting the variable into the payload within the Task state would be to add a Pass state which adds the execution ID to the input like:

```
AddExecutionId: {
  Type: "Pass",
  InputPath: "$$.Execution.Id",
  ResultPath: "$.executionId",
  Next: "Lambda"
}
```

and then you can pass the entire input as `Payload.$`, since it now includes the ID, like:

```
Lambda: {
  Type: "Task",
  Resource: "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
  Parameters: {
    "Payload.$": "$",
    "FunctionName": "<arn>"
  },
  ...
}
```

Of course, you could also nest the execution ID and provide some subset of the input as `Payload.$` if you wanted.

This example is derived from the [public documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-example.html) near the bottom of the page.